# PDF of the summation of L lognormal RVs

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Given the following summation

$$\gamma = \sum_{l=1}^{L} y_{l},$$
where the PDF of $Y$ follows the lognormal distribution and is given by

$$f_{Y}(y)=\frac{10}{y\ln(10)\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{(-10\log_{10}(y) - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right).$$

Is is possible to find the resulting PDF?

I know it is quite complicated to find such resulting PDF, but a good approximation would also work.

Answer (score 2):

The case $L=2$ is studied in [Sums of Lognormals](http://ozdaniel.com/A/DufresneLognormalsARC2008.pdf). There is no exact closed form expression. Approximations are discussed in [Estimating the Distribution of a Sum of Independent Lognormal Random Variables](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3158832_Estimating_the_Distribution_of_a_Sum_of_Independent_Lognormal_Random_Variables).